# Parameter 5 of constructor in ... required a bean of type '...Mapper' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Description:

Parameter 5 of constructor in com.example.springmysqlelastic.utils.ElasticSynchronizer required a bean of type 'com.example.springmysqlelastic.mapper.FoodMapper' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.springmysqlelastic.mapper.FoodMapper' in your configuration.

**There is a MySQL to Elasticsearch sync module and all was working for User entity. Then i added new Food entity. I set files. But now im getting Bean error on FoodMapper.**
Project info: food, restaurant, user search on Elasticsearch engine with Spring.

FoodMapper.java

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface FoodMapper {

    FoodDTO toFoodDTO(Food food);

    List<FoodDTO> toFoodDtos(List<Food> foods);

    Food toFood(FoodDTO foodDTO);

    List<Food> toFoods(List<FoodDTO> foodDTOS);

    FoodModel toFoodModel(Food food);
}
```

UserMapper.java

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {

    UserDTO toUserDTO(User user);

    List<UserDTO> toUserDtos(List<User> users);

    User toUser(UserDTO userDTO);

    List<User> toUsers(List<UserDTO> userDTOS);

    UserModel toUserModel(User user);
}
```

FoodService.java

```
@Service
public class FoodService implements IFoodService {

    private IFoodDAO foodDAO;
    private FoodMapper foodMapper;

    @Autowired
    public FoodService(IFoodDAO foodDAO, FoodMapper foodMapper) {
        this.foodDAO = foodDAO;
        this.foodMapper = foodMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public FoodDTO save(FoodDTO foodDTO) {
        Food food = this.foodDAO.save(this.foodMapper.toFood(foodDTO));
        return this.foodMapper.toFoodDTO(food);
    }

    @Override
    public FoodDTO findById(Long id) {
        return this.foodMapper.toFoodDTO(this.foodDAO.findById(id).orElse(null));
    }

    @Override
    public List<FoodDTO> findAll() {
        return this.foodMapper.toFoodDtos(this.foodDAO.findAll());
    }


}
```

ElasticSynchorizer.java

```
@Service
public class ElasticSynchronizer {

    private IUserDAO userDAO;
    private IUserESRepo userESRepo;
    private UserMapper userMapper;
    private IFoodDAO foodDAO;
    private IFoodESRepo foodESRepo;
    private FoodMapper foodMapper;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSynchronizer.class);

    @Autowired
    public ElasticSynchronizer(IUserDAO userDAO, IUserESRepo userESRepo, UserMapper userMapper, IFoodDAO foodDAO, IFoodESRepo foodESRepo, FoodMapper foodMapper) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
        this.userESRepo = userESRepo;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
        this.foodDAO = foodDAO;
        this.foodESRepo = foodESRepo;
        this.foodMapper = foodMapper;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */3 * * * *")
    @Transactional
    public void sync() {
        LOG.info("Start Syncing Users - {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        this.syncUsers();
        LOG.info(" End Syncing Users - {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        LOG.info("Start Syncing Foods- {}", LocalDateTime.now());
        this.syncFoods();
        LOG.info(" End Syncing Foods - {}", LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    private void syncUsers() {

        Specification<User> userSpecification = (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
                getModificationDatePredicate(criteriaBuilder, root);
        List<User> userList;
        if (userESRepo.count() == 0) {
            userList = userDAO.findAll();
        } else {
            userList = userDAO.findAll(userSpecification);
        }
        for(User user: userList) {
            LOG.info("Syncing User - {}", user.getId());
            userESRepo.save(this.userMapper.toUserModel(user));
        }
    }
    private void syncFoods() {

        Specification<Food> userSpecification = (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) ->
                getModificationDatePredicate(criteriaBuilder, root);
        List<Food> foodList;
        if (userESRepo.count() == 0) {
            foodList = foodDAO.findAll();
        } else {
            foodList = foodDAO.findAll(userSpecification);
        }
        for(Food food: foodList) {
            LOG.info("Syncing Food - {}", food.getId());
            foodESRepo.save(this.foodMapper.toFoodModel(food));
        }
    }
    private static Predicate getModificationDatePredicate(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<?> root) {
        Expression<Timestamp> currentTime;
        currentTime = cb.currentTimestamp();
        Expression<Timestamp> currentTimeMinus = cb.literal(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis() -
                (Constants.INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDE)));
        return cb.between(root.<Date>get(Constants.MODIFICATION_DATE),
                currentTimeMinus,
                currentTime
        );
    }
}
```

Food.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Food {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private String imglink;
    private String restaurant;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date modificationDate;

    
}
```

Foodmodel.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Document(indexName = "food") //type deprecate oldu hepsi artik _doc
public class FoodModel {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private String imglink;
    private String restaurant;
    private Date modificationDate;
}
```

FoodDTO.java

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class FoodDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private float price;
    private String category;
    private String description;
    private String imglink;
    private String restaurant;
}
```

IFoodDAO.java

```
@Repository
public interface IFoodDAO extends JpaRepository<Food, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Food> {
    //List<User> findByNameContaining(String name);
}
```

IFoodESRepo.java

```
public interface IFoodESRepo extends ElasticsearchRepository<FoodModel, Long> {
      //List<Food> findByNameContaining(String name);

}
```

main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories("com.example.springmysqlelastic.repo.elastic")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.springmysqlelastic.repo")
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.springmysqlelastic"})
//@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class SpringMysqlElasticApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(SpringMysqlElasticApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mvP7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVCiS.png)

Comment: This _should_ work; when I get this error, it's usually because I've edited the `*Mapper.java` file and it hasn't recompiled (IDE out of sync or such), and a clean build usually fixes it.

Comment: so no problem using multiple mappers instead of one?

Comment: Not as a general rule, no, as long as they're of distinct types.

Answer (score 1):

I found that i can't use multiple mappers. Moved second mapper to first now works.
Don't use more than 1 mapper.

Comment: still have bean problem